# await for all of the async request to finish inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, axios

I need to push all the results into an array making async http calls but i need to wait until all of the calls are finished.

```
async function(){
  const arrayWithResults = [];
  const urls = ['someurl.com', 'otherurl.com'];
  urls.map( url => {
    axios.get(url).then( result => {
      arrayWithResults.push(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Is using await the only option here? i'm afraid of using it since awaiting for each request would slow down the whole process.

Comment: But potentially better answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` the return value of `Promise.all` instead:

```
const arrayWithResults = await Promise.all(
  urls.map(url => axios.get(url))
);
```

`Promise.all` returns a promise that resolves as soon as all promises passed to it are resolved.